# Checkbox attribute checked in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How I can set a checked attribute for an input in my form, using Thymeleaf?
Here is my code, which currently doesn't work:

```
<label th:each="cat : ${categories}">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" 
        th:value="${cat.id}" 
        th:text="${cat.description}"
        th:checked="${recipe.getCategories().contains(cat) ? true : false}"
    />
</label>
```

Comment: add relevant code also so that can understand what exactly it returns recipe.getCategories()...as syntax looks fine.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is elsewhere. The syntax you have works (although the ternary isn't needed... `${recipe.getCategories().contains(cat)}` would be sufficient.

Comment: **getCategories()** return a HashSet of some class CategoryCommand, and **categories** are HashSet of same class, but **contains()** always return **false**.
All objects for both sets are in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, the problem may be from somewhere else but try this and see if it helps:

```
th:checked="${recipe.getCategories().contains(cat)}"
```

Comment: The `th:checked` attribute requires a boolean result.

Comment: I removed the second expression.